# Could not obtain certification chain, err The supplied identity is not valid , Verify() returned x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to build network, I'm follow [this](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) link. When I'm generating network artifacts, it builds successfully using this command `./byfn.sh -m generate`. Next I'm up the network as mentioned in guide using this command `./byfn.sh -m up`, but I'm having this error

> " [Could not obtain certification chain, err The supplied identity is not valid
>   , Verify() returned x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid]
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========".

Can someone help me to bring up the network?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or macOS by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some buffer time between key generation and execution of the rest of the code. That did the trick for me.

All that should be required is adding e.g. `sleep 300` after cryptogen and configtxgen have been called but **before** the actual docker containers get spun up and the api calls get made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Docker on Windows or Mac (and especially if you are running Docker Toolbox), then the issue is likely caused by a time seen between your host system and the underlying VM used by Docker.

I'd suggest totally restarting Docker on Windows or Mac